# command to pull only numbers from a output

Tags: shell, scripting

ssh to remote device and pulling packet loss counter.

```
$ ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0* | grep -E "Tot Pkt Lost"
```

Output of above command:

```
Tot Pkt Lost       : 1083761951
```

I need a command which will pull only Tot Pkt lost numbers.

Comment: I like to use `cut -d ':' -f 2` for its simplicity. You'll have to get rid of the extra space though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 'cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0*' | 
    grep -oP 'Tot Pkt Lost\s*:\s*\K\d+'
1083761951
```

But `awk` might be both simpler and more portable here:

```
ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 'cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0*' | 
    awk '/Tot Pkt Lost/{print $NF}'
1083761951
```

Comment: Thank you. Figure it out the answer after my post. Appreciate your help

Comment: @ShubChowdhury You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `-E` with `grep` in that instance as you don't use an extended regular expression.  You also expand the globbing pattern on on the local machine rather than on the remote system, which may give you the wrong results.

Your command should therefore be rewritten as

```
ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 'cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0*' |
grep -F 'Tot Pkt Lost'
```

I'm using `-F` with `grep` here since I'm matching with a string, not a regular expression. I'm also quoting the command that should be executed on the remote host so that the globbing pattern is expanded there, not locally.

This should give you the same output:

```
Tot Pkt Lost       : 1083761951
```

To get only digits from this, just pass it through `grep -E -o '[[:digit:]]+'`:

```
ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 'cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0*' |
grep -F 'Tot Pkt Lost' |
grep -E -o '[[:digit:]]+'
```

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
ssh dlpremote@172.19.37.188 'cat /proc/net/pf_ring/*eth0*' |
sed -n 's/^Tot Pkt Lost.*: //p'
```

This would match the `Tot Pkt Lost` string at the beginning of each line, and the `:`  after it. It would delete the matched string and print the remainder of the line.  All other data is discarded.